# How to query archived product

Tags: soql, product

I noticed that archived products don't get returned in soql. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Example query:

```
SELECT Id, IsArchived FROM Product2 WHERE Id = '01t50000001CQp6' AND IsArchived = true
```

This product is archived and I can view it in the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add ALL ROWS to the query..  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm

Comment: I get an error of parsing error with queries `SELECT Id, IsArchived FROM Product2 WHERE IsArchived = true ALL ROWS` AND `SELECT Id, IsArchived FROM Product2  ALL ROWS WHERE IsArchived = true`

Comment: @TemporaryFix If you're using the Developer Console Query tab, you can't query those records. Try the Apex Data Loader or Workbench to perform a "queryAll" call, or use ALL ROWS when using Apex (e.g. Execute Anonymous).